# Show that $g(w) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{zf'(z)}{f(z) - w}dz$ is analytic and discuss the properties of $g$.

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula, analytic-functions, rouches-theorem

Let $f$ be analytic in $\overline{B}(0;1)$ with $f(0) = 0, f'(0) \neq 0$ and $f(z) \neq 0$ for $0 < |z| \leq R.$ Put $\rho = \min\{|f(z)|: |z| = R
\} > 0$. Define $g: B(0,\rho) \to \mathbb{C}$ by

$$ g(w) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{zf'(z)}{f(z) - w}dz$$

where $\gamma$ is the circle $|z| = R$. Show that $g$ is analytic is analytic and discuss the properties of $g$.

This is similar to the Cauchy Formula but is in the section of The argument principle and Rouche's Theorem (Conway's Complex Analysis Book) and I really don't have a clue how to prove this. Can anyone help me?

Maybe should I consider the power series of the analytic function $f$ ?

Comment: Where does the integrand have poles, and what is the residue there?

Comment: The integrand has poles at the fixed points of f where f(w) = w. And the residue of f or g ?

Comment: I guess he meant the residue of the integrand

Comment: There's a typo in the integrand, it's supposed to be $$\frac{z f'(z)}{f(z) - w}.$$ If it were $f(w) - w$ in the denominator, $g$ would be identically $0$ [resp. undefined for $w$ with $\lvert w\rvert < \min\{\rho,1\}$ and $f(w) = w$]. May be a typo in the book.

Comment: I fixed the typo, you were right. Thanks.

Comment: So, for fixed $w$, where does the integrand have poles, and what is its residue there?

Comment: To me it is weird to introduce this integral without saying where it comes from. An hint could be $w = f(a)$